# Correct syntax for using YASM assembler

Tags: assembly, syntax-error, yasm

When using the YASM assembler there are times when I get a syntax error upon input such as:

> **nop dword [ds:rax+rax+0x0]** or **nop dword [eax+eax]**, etc.

disassembled:

```
00000001000a1000 0F1F440000      nop        dword [ds:rax+rax+0x0]
```

what is the correct way to input this without getting a syntax error?

Comment: If you were able to input this construct, what would you expect it to do? To my absolute astonishment, Nasm will assemble this. Apparently it's just a multi-byte `nop`(?). Where did you find such a thing???

Comment: You're absolutely correct, it is a multi-byte nop. It's nicer looking this way in my opinion, especially when you've got several nops in a row; [(Here's a reference showing different lengths)](http://www.asmpedia.org/index.php?title=NOP). How did you input it the assembly without getting a syntax error? that's what i need to know.

Comment: I did it in Nasm, not Yasm. The two "should" be pretty similar... but perhaps not in this case. Just `nop dword [eax]`, etc...